# Sorting string numerically and then alphabetically

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting

I have the following character array in C:

`38ch50ej16af49di27bg`

how can I sort it in increasing numerical order and then alphabetical order to produce a string like this?

`1234567890abcdefghij`

all letters have the same casing

Comment: Sorting by "alphabetical" order already achieves what you want since `0` < `1` < ... < `A` < ... < `Z` < ... < `a` < ... < `z`. I.E. `(char)'0' < (char)'1' < ...`

Comment: Research sorting algorithms, pick an appropriate one and then implement it. Counting sort for example would work well in this case.

Comment: @kikikey What you need is to write a function that splits a string into two partitions and then to use qsort to sort each partition.

Comment: Here is a counting sort version like Sam suggested earlier: https://onlinegdb.com/0wt4UETww

Comment: @MarcoBonelli If there is used the EBCDIC character table then your statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to use the [`qsort` or `qsort_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function if any of those are available in your implementation.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *lhs, const void *rhs) {
    unsigned char l = *((const unsigned char*)lhs);
    unsigned char r = *((const unsigned char*)rhs);
    
    return l < r ? -1          // left < right ?
                 : r < l ? 1   // right < left ?
                         : 0;  // equal
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "38ch50ej16af49di27bg";

    qsort(str, sizeof str - 1, sizeof *str, compare);

    puts(str);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sE5zaqd91)